# Google Map API Errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating a dynamic map with the Google Maps API and I'm getting hard to understand errors from only certain markers. My page is located at:

http://dmatesic.com/RaC/Customized%20Google%20Map/google_map.html

My (long) java script source file is located at:

http://dmatesic.com/RaC/Customized%20Google%20Map/js/google_map.js

Everything is working fine except for one marker. If you click on "SERVICOS" and then select the sub category "Repuestos de Autos" I am getting odd errors from the google map main.js file.

In Firefox I get:

```
c is undefined
http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/193c/maps2.api/main.js
Line 600
```

In IE:

```
'x' is null or not an object  main.js, line 600 character 83
```

I have no idea why everything is working except for this one sub category/marker. If there any other details I can provide to help us solve this problem, please let me know.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are getting error because `getZoomFactor` return `NaN`, and after that you are calling `setCenter` method with zoom `NaN`.

This is the line that is causing problem.

```
zoom = getZoomFactor(minLatitude, maxLatitude, minLongitude, maxLongitude, centerLatitude, centerLongitude, 600);
map.setCenter(centerPoint, zoom);
```